# Efficient method of blanking values that appear less than X times in a column using Hadoop

Tags: perl, hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

*UPDATED TO NOTE CHANGE TO AGGREGATE KEY*

### Description

I have a requirement in an anonymized environment to remove **all values** from a column of a file that occur less than a specified number of times. There will be multiple columns specified that require values to appear more than X times within that column and the blanking is relative to a column. Meaning if X = 4 and the value 123 occurs 3 times in column 1 and 4 times in column 4 then all 3 occurrences must be blanked in column 1 but are allowable in column 4.

I have solved this issues using a 2 pass approach leveraging Hadoop Streaming and Perl that has been stable for the past half year. The issue is that a new file has been provided that, although my process will handle it, it will take roughly 5 days to process on our 862 container (54 Node) hadoop cluster. I will explain my solution/approach and ask for any optimizations or alternative methods that would fit this problem and allow for optimized run times.

File stats being processed:

- Size 1.4TB
- Columns 19,427
- Records 22.1mil
- Elements 429,336,700,000

### 2 Pass Approach (Current)

#### Pass 1

This Pass uses Hadoop streaming with a Perl (v5.10.1) Mapper and Perl reducer to get a count for every value in every column (count relative to each column) of the input file and build a lookup file if the count is greater the the specified X containing column, value, count.

**Mapper:** Use Perl hashing to build a hash of hashes that contains the column, value, count where the count is incremented with each occurrence of the value for that column:

```
$ColValCntHash{ $col }{ $value }++;
```

As this is the mapper using hadoop streaming, I print the results in the following Key Value format to allow a more distributed allocation to the reducers:

```
col|value\tcount
```

this produces an aggregate key of column # and the field value and then assigns the count of that value in that column as the key.

**Reducer:** read the col|value\tcount passed to it, parse the key, build a hash to sum the counts of the values passed in from multiple mappers.

```
$FinalCountHash{ $col }{ $value } += $count;
```

At the end, each reducer prints col, value, and count into the output file if the count is less than the specified X.

**First Pass Results:** Pass 1 produces a "lookup" list that is sourced into pass 2 where the blanking occurs and is structured as :

```
Col\tValue\tCount
1\t123\t3
3\t234\t2
```

#### Pass 2

This Pass uses Hadoop streaming with only a Perl Mapper (no reduce phase) to blank the values in the input file if they exist on the lookup file generated by pass 1.

**Mapper:** The mapper requires that the lookup file be shipped along side the Perl code distributed to each node so that it can be used to build a lookup hash like:

```
$aggKey = $col . "|" . $value;
$LookupHash{ $aggKey }=1;
```

the aggKey is used to reduce the memory overhead of the Hash of Hashes and now is just a hash which brought the number of values i can buffer into memory to around 22 mil.

As the input records are passed through the mapper, the columns are iterated over and the hash is checked to see if the column and value exists. if so, then the value in the column is replaced with a blank.

**Pass 2 output:**
Pass 2 generated an output file (part files) that contains an "anonymized" version of the input file.

### Issue

Even though the cluster has plenty of memory (2.4TB combined), this is divided among containers and at most pass 2 can load around 22mil values from the look up file before the container fails with a memory issue. This required a iterative blanking to occur on the input by splitting the lookup file into 22mil chunks and running them against the main file in multiple passes of pass 2. the entire process of a 10-100 GB file runs in 5 to 20 minutes depending on the number of values to blank.

Now that I have a file of the 1.4TB size to process through this with almost 20k columns, the resulting lookup file contains 4.6 Billion records (roughly 1% of the total values in the file which is relative % for previous files).

With the memory limitation of only loading 22mil lookup values at a time... this leaves my current process needing to pass over the input file in pass 2 210 times.. and with it having to read the 1.4 TB file (which shrinks slightly with each pass of removals), each of these passes take ~25 minutes.

I hope this adequately describes the problem/current solution/issues adequately. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Hadoop, but the memory issue is likely the byproduct of building `%LookupHash` in *Pass 2*.

Based on the description of the problem, *Pass 2* doesn't need to know how many times the value 123 occurred in column 1, just that the value 123 needs to be blanked out.

In that case, your `%LookupHash` can be made to consume a lot less memory by storing array references instead of hash references. My testing shows that this should reduce memory by 50%:

```
my %LookupHash;
while (<>) {
    my ( $col, $value ) = split /\t/, $_, 2;
    push @{ $LookupHash{$col} }, $value;
}
```

Come to think of it, a list of values to match against is what is required, so regex-ify it:

```
for my $col ( keys %LookupHash ) {
    my $values = join '|', map { '^' . $_. '$' } @{ $LookupHash{$col} };
    $LookupHash{$col} = $values;
}
```

And then using it should be a doddle:

```
$value = '' if $value =~ qr/$LookupHash{$col}/;
```

---

Better yet, avoid creating the array references altogether and rely instead on building the regex strings manually (this should consume an order of magnitude less memory):

```
my %LookupHash;
while (<>) {
    my ( $col, $value ) = split /\t/, $_, 2;
    if ( $LookupHash{$col} ) {
       $LookupHash{$col} = join '|', $LookupHash{$col}, $value;
    }
    else {
       $LookupHash{$col} = $value;
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
$value = '' if $value =~ qr/^(?:$LookupHash{$col})$/;
```

Comment: Thank you Zaid. Last night I attempted to build the lookup by first aggregating the col and the value and using that aggregation as the key and just assigning a 1 to the value. this did free up some memory as it was no longer having to allocate 2 hashes for every entry. But your method would be even more efficient I think in terms of memory. I will give this a try and see what gains i see. thanks!

Comment: @marmalope there is even more scope for reducing the footprint. If I have time I will add more details, but the gist of the enhancement is to avoid creating the array references altogether and use strings directly

Comment: So this approach significantly shrunk the memory consumed by about 65%... but it increased the run time from 15 to 90 minutes per pass. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @marmalope There will be a trade-off for sure, but the speed may have something to do with the way I set up the regex. I just posted an alternative approach that might fare a little better.

Comment: @marmalope I think it would be relevant for you to post what version of Perl your system is using, because certain regex trie optimizations were introduced after version 5.10.

Comment: thank you again. it looks like the increase in run time is only partially due to the regex lookup. 60% of the run time is now spent in building the hash lookup. I very much appreciate the help. but i am starting to think, this solution may not be the optimal fit to the problem... I'm just not sure what is at this point. Also. I am updating the post with the Perl version ( v5.10.1). Thank you.